# set a block of pixels to a colour opencv

Tags: python, opencv

is there a way to set a rectangular block of pixels to a colour in opencv (specifically in python) other than looping through them? e.g. some kind of 2d slice syntax or once an ROI is set change all inside.

i have tried `im[0:100, 200:300] = (255,255,255)` with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at CV.Rectangle, which does exactly what you want :)
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_drawing_functions.html?highlight=rectangle#Rectangle

Answer (score 2):

`im[0:100,200:300] = [255,255,255]` works fine for me.

Eg:

```
>>> im = cv2.imread('baboon.jpg')
>>> im[0:2,200:202]
array([[[180, 200, 181],
        [164, 190, 166]],

       [[170, 182, 164],
        [124, 134, 118]]], dtype=uint8)
>>> im[0:100,200:300] = [255,255,255]
>>> im[0:2,200:202]
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Another method is cv2.rectangle

`cv2.rectangle(im,(200,0),(300,100),(255,255,255),-1)`

But it seems cv2.rectangle is more faster (around 5x) than previous slicing method(as per my tesing)